# Eval retorna valores corretos apenas na criação

Tags: vba, vb.net, excel-vba, visual-basic-6, vbs

Tenho uma planilha financeira com várias planilhas (mês a mês).
crie a seguinte macro:

```
'
' Macro_vinculo Macro
'
Public Function eval(ByVal str As String) As Variant

  eval = Application.Evaluate(str)

End Function
```

e os comandos para buscarem valores das planilhas sequentes, por exemplo:

```
=@Eval(MAIÚSCULA(TEXTO(DATAM($A$26;1);"mmm"))&"!$G$23")
```

Quando criado, funcionou perfeitamente porém, quando altero os dados nas planilhas sequentes, o comando não atualiza os valores tornando a planilha incorreta!
Saberiam alguma solução para este problema?

Comment: Por que `javascript` e `php` em uma pergunta sobre `vb`?

Comment: Desculpe! Foi um erro! É VBA, vou corrigir! Obrigado! Abraço!